# How to instance objects from a unicode string in Python

Tags: python, string, object, instance

I have the following problem:

```
# testcase is a list object  
i=0
for e in testcase:
    testclass = e['class']              #unicode Object
    properties = e['properties']        #dict Object

    probertie = testcase[i]['properties']

    tester = test.ScreenshotCounterTest.ScreenshotCounterTest(probertie)

    #tester = InstanceClass(testclass,propertie)

    tester.checkResults()
    i=i+1
```

The unicode object `testclass` contains several unicode strings like `test.ScreenshotCounterTest` or `FileExistTest`

I need a way to initialize these Objects with the property argument

a way to dynamically create objects from this `testclass` list object.

Thanks for your help

Comment: you're probably looking for the `eval()` function. It takes a string as an argument and returns the result of what would happen if that string was the actual code

Comment: I would create a dict that holds the string and corresponding class though it may look redundant.

Comment: no the eval() function doesn't help me

Comment: how did the objects get in testcase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get what you need, then this should help you:

```
import importlib

qual_name = "my.module.MyClass"
splitted = qual_name.split(".")
class_name = splitted[-1]
module_name = ".".join(splitted[:-1])

module_obj = importlib.import_module(module_name)
class_obj = getattr(module_obj, class_name)
class_inst = class_obj()   # this is instance of my.module.MyClass; assuming that this class has no-argument constructor; in other case use constructor arguments here
```

[`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) interface may have changed between p2.7 and p3k, I'm not sure. Also, there is (was?) `__import__` built-in function, but I find `importlib` most reliable.

In your case `testclass`/`e['class']` will be used instead of `qual_name`, and `tester` should be assigned like `class_inst` in this example.

Comment: OK when i take your solution i get TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: print value of module_name variable and paste it here. Do the same with qual_name, and class_name.

Comment: module_name = test

qual_name = test.ScreenshotCounterTest

class_name = ScreenshotCounterTest

Comment: In your example you used class name test.ScreenshotCounterTest.ScreenshotCounterTest as class name, and that seems to be the problem. ScreenshotCounterTest is both package name (subpackage of test package) and class name. Change qual_name, so it contains full name of class you want to instantiate, then it should work.

Comment: THANK YOU 
yes thats the problem, the packacke name and the class name are the same therefore it has to be test.ScreenshotCounterTest.ScreenshotCounterTest

Comment: At your service, I'm here to help ;)

Comment: Oh, I would forget - it won't work if class is in the same module in which you want to instantiate it dynamically. Workaround is quite easy, you'll find it yourself if you need it.